# minio upgrade issue xml invalid

Tags: minio

Task: Trying to upgrade from minio.netcore 1.1.1 client to minio client 3.1.13

Problem: When i try to create a bucket with the new client I get the following excpetion thrown:

```
MinIO API responded with message=The XML you provided was not well-formed or 
did not validate against our published schema
```

I've tested in isolation from the rest of my code and can't see what the issue is:

```
  using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
       
       var client = new Minio.MinioClient("{serverIpAddress}:9000", "myaccesskey", "mysecretkey");
       var bucketid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        await client.MakeBucketAsync(bucketid,"uk-st-1");
        var result = await client.BucketExistsAsync(bucketid);
    }
}
}
```

and my csproj is switching between these 2 nugets:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Minio" Version="3.1.13" />
<!--<PackageReference Include="Minio.NetCore" Version="1.1.1" />-->
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've tried catching the traffic and the XML it produces for both nugets is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <q1:CreateBucketConfiguration xmlns:q1="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <q1:LocationConstraint>uk-st-1</q1:LocationConstraint>
  </q1:CreateBucketConfiguration>
```